# Manipulate text in a loaded html-page of the Webbrowser control in the DocumentCompleted event (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, winforms-to-web

I already tried some solutions provided here, but I cannot get it to work. On my winform I have a webbrowser control which should load a webpage (aspx). In case the webpage isn't found, I want to let the user know that this page isn't found. To get this to work I use the following code:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    If (WebBrowser1.Document.Url.ToString().StartsWith("res:")) Then
        Dim curDir As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
        Dim Url As Uri = New Uri(String.Format("file:///{0}/Html/PageNotFound.html", curDir))            
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(Url)
    End If
End Sub
```

This is working fine. The page PageNotFound.html is shown. However, I would like to provide the user with some additional information which I want to insert into the PageNotFound.html at realtime (i.e. using document.getElementById to manipulate a Label-tag). I just don't know how I can do this, or if it is even possible. Maybe I use the wrong event. something I also tried is:

```
 With WebBrowser1
     .Navigate("about:blank")
     .Document.OpenNew(False)
     .Document.Write(HtmlString)
     .Refresh()
 End With
```

Where the HtmlString contains a complete webform.(like: "")

Maybe someone put me the right direction? TIA

Comment: `WebBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank")` is async. You should handle `DocumentCompleted` and do `Document.Write` from there.

Comment: I do use the Documentcompleted-event to manipulate the HtmlString.